# change xmlelement name using linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Good day fellow programmers.

My team leader gave me a task where i need to convert xml file to html5

i don't want to use xslt, that's why i'm going to use c# with the help of 
System.xml.

but im  new to LINQ and c#

specifically: what i'm going to do is remove the element with TAGS name.

this is my xml file

```
<Root>
    <Paragraph>
        <Tags>
            Just some text
        </Tags>
    </Paragraph>
    <AnotherTag>
        <Paragraph>
            <Tags>
            Another Text
            </Tags>
        </Paragraph>
    </AnotherTag>
</Root>
```

and the possible output is:

```
<Root>
    <Paragraph>

            Just some text

    </Paragraph>
    <AnotherTag>
        <Paragraph>

            Another Text

        </Paragraph>
    </AnotherTag>
</Root>
```

what it does is it removes the TAGS but its Content remains in their position

this is my c# code:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("myxml.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> tagsToremove =
            from el in root.Descendants("Tags")
            select el;
        foreach (XElement el in tagsToremove)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el);
        }
```

so what i need is the code for Removing the Node only. thank you.

Comment: try : el.ReplaceWith(el.Value);

Comment: yes i tried that. but if i used that code it gives me error message:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. and the cursor is at the "in"

Comment: Tags to remove must be null.  I usually use : List<XElement> tagsToremove = root.Descendants("Tags").ToList();

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest copy the content to parent element and use `XElement.Remove` method to remove the element.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

    var elements = doc.Descendants("Tags");

    foreach(var element in elements)
    {
        var content  = (string)element.Value;
        var parent = element.Parent;            

        element.Remove();
        parent.Add(content);        

    }
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FMV6dY)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(pathToFile);
foreach (var tag in doc.Descendants("Tags").ToList())
    tag.ReplaceWith((string)tag);
```

Note the `ToList()` call there.  You're modifying the document within the loop so you need to collect all the tags to be replaced first.